# Google Drive API List Folders GET

Tags: python, get, google-drive-api, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to query Google Drive for a certain file to find its url. Here is my code. The only thing I changed was my API key is substituted with AAAAAAAAAA

```
    queryString = urllib.quote_plus("title = \'" + filename + "\'")
    parameters = {'key':'{AAAAAAAAAA}', 'q': queryString}
    inserted_file = requests.get('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files', params = parameters)
    print (inserted_file.url)
    print inserted_file
```

when I print inserted_file, it returns error 400. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[400 error](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request) response means the `value` supplied is invalid or the combination of provided fields is invalid. Its user error. This can mean that a required field or parameter has not been provided.

It might gives you `API key not valid` or `Bad request` message/

```
"message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key."

"message": "Bad Request"
```

It is recommended to generate/use valid credentials. There is a documentation how to get credentials/ steps to run sample project here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/python#top_of_page